# Put eform's label and textfield(input) separate

Tags: 8, entities

I'm working on creating a table with eForm in Drupal 8.

Since label and textfield(input) stick together, can I insert label and textfield(input) into separate `<td>`?

Answer (score 0):

The Render API, similar in Drupal 7, allows you to add a [#theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/group/theme_render/8) property to use a [hook_theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_theme/8) defined template. The theme definition should use "render element", and that will be available in the template preprocess function. The way that it's usually done is to modify or create the render array in the preprocess function, and set #theme to table (in Drupal 7 calling theme('table') was possible).

Edit: Removed second paragraph which referred to modifying the theme.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm only creating a module for this. So, no theme is not available to me.

Comment: Theme/Templates are defined in modules via hook_theme and the current D8 standard is to place the templates within the module's templates/ directory.